# Два сказуемых в предложении?

Tags: синтаксис

Предложение такого типа: "Он пошел налить себе чаю". Я уже не очень помню школьный курс синтаксиса, но все-таки интересно: как разобрать это предложение? И "пошел", и "налить" будут сказуемыми?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сказуемое одно: пошел. Пошел зачем? Налить. Обстоятельство цели, выраженное инфинитивом.

Comment: Решили рискнуть послать сходить найти купить выпить... (С) нармуд